# Change the registry setting for an exe to always display on the secondary monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, registry

Is there a registry setting in the windows XP Operating system  where i can change the setting so that whenever i launch my application it always sits on the secondary monitor??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) has a feature to tell certain application to open on a desired monitor/position.
[image]